# How can i get this code to not defy my if statement

Tags: if-statement, octave

Hello so i was asked to write a code at uni in octave language and i have a problem with my  code no matter what the input my if statement doesnt care about the else command and runs the code after the if anyways my code is down below could use some help !

```
fid=fopen('myfile.txt','r');
if(fid=-1)
disp('Lost')
else
disp('Found')
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I had no idea Octave supported this mess, but you were bitten by the traditional "assignment instead of equality testing" typo (commonly encountered in C).

Here's example output from a completely fresh octave session:

```matlab
octave:1> if (x=1); disp(x); end
warning: suggest parenthesis around assignment used as truth value
1
```

There's no error due to the undefined `x`, because `x=1` assigns to `x` and then evaluates to `1`. So in your case the `fid` is overwritten with `-1` and then tested for being `-1`. Also note the warning printed by the parser.

You need a double equals sign for equality testing:

```matlab
octave:2> if (y==1); disp(y); end
error: 'y' undefined near line 1, column 1
```

One controversial strategy to avoid this kind of bug in such broken languages is to use [Yoda conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions), i.e. `if (-1 == fid) ...` because this would give you an error in case of the same typo.

Comment: I would also add the point that wrapping parentheses around the expression evaluated by `if` is completely unnecessary. Hence the whole 'wrap the assignment around (double) parentheses to signal intent and remove this warning' strategy by octave.